# Scanline usage (x offset)

Tags: delphi

I am working on drawing an image, using ImageEnVect (or TImage).
I use ScanLine, but normally my image does not loading line by line.

Here is how my image must load.
[image]

```
procedure TJP2RenderPreview.put_region(size : _Ckdu_coords; buf : array of Integer; offX, offY : Integer);
var
  x, y          : Integer;
  width, height : Integer;
  buf_pos       : Integer;
  RowPtr        : PRGBTriple;
begin
  width:= size.__property_get_x;
  height:= size.__property_get_y;
  buf_pos:=0;

  for y := offY to offY + height - 1  do
  begin
    RowPtr:= formMain.imgPreview.Bitmap.ScanLine[y];
    for x := offX to offX + width - 1  do
    begin
//    RowPtr.rgbReserved      := (buf[buf_pos] div $1000000);
      RowPtr.rgbtRed:= ((buf[buf_pos] mod $1000000) div $10000);
      RowPtr.rgbtGreen:= ((buf[buf_pos] mod $10000) div $100);
      RowPtr.rgbtBlue:= (buf[buf_pos] mod $100);
      Inc(RowPtr);
      Inc(buf_pos);
    end;
  end;
  formMain.imgPreview.Refresh;
  formMain.imgPreview.Update;
end;
```

When the third section come, i want to start my scanline's X coordinate on OFFSETX value. But it starts 0 and drawing over.

I edited my code part. All color values like(1239223) come in array part by part.
I give you offset and width/height value :

```
First call : OffX : 0, OffY: 0, Width: 100; Height: 50;
Second : OffX : 0, OffY: 50, Width: 100; Height: 50; 
Third : OffX : 100, OffY: 0, Width: 100; Height: 50;
Last :  OffX : 100, OffY: 50, Width: 100; Height: 50;
```

drawing X= 0 and image drawing over, but offsetX = 500; :

[image]

Comment: We don't know what type any of the variables are. We don't know what pixel format is in use. We don't know what `width`, `height` or any of the other variables are. And it's also not clear what the problem is. I suggest that you provide a short but complete program, show what the output is, and show what the output should be.

Comment: i added more information, can you look again?

Comment: I can't make sense of this. I don't understand why you can't just show a complete program so that we don't have to guess. Probably somebody will be able to wring a question out of this. But it's beyond me. Sorry.

Comment: i am using kakadu software sdk (.dll COM Object), so kakadu gives me an image's color array. But i dont know, how size give. For example, i want image(100x100) from kakadu sdk and it gives me a (100x10) ten times. But another time it gives a (50x50 - and 50x50) I cant handle it. I just know dimensions.

Comment: Also i just have an array (width*height) and offset size. But i dont know how many times will call this function. For example if kakadu 3000x3000 image gives an 3000x100 . this function call 30 times. I hope i explain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't set RowPtr properly before the x-cycle.  It always points to 0th pixel of scanline.
Try

```
 Inc(RowPtr, OffX);
 for x := 0 to width - 1...
```